# After using ssl certificate, wordpress doesn't work

Tags: php, ssl

Before I configure my apache to ssl, the wordpress work fine. But after that, it shows like this. 
[image]
However, it's not because the php doesn't work. Since I got this
[image]
The picture above shows php works fine, so I guess it's because there is some problems with wordpress. Anyone could fix that? Thanks!

Comment: phpmyadmin will have a separate <location> configuration, that's already set up by the look of it. You'll have to copy the configuration you have for the original site into the SSL version of the site too.

Comment: This seems to be an apache configuration rather than a wordpress issue. But to still be of service, why don't you try to revert to the old config file for the wordpress page and see if that restores the webpage.